# How to return Task.FromResult<bool>(true) using mono cecil?

Tags: c#, generics, mono.cecil

I need to use mono cecil to implement the following logic.

```
public Task<bool> MyTask()
{
    return Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
}
```

I only know how to invoke non-generic method, since there are corresponding demo code in the cecil project. I don't know how to invoke generic method. Could anyone tell me how to do that please? The corresponding IL code should look like this:

ldc.i4.1
call class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::FromResult(!!0)
ret

This is what I have right now:

```
void Main()
{
    AssemblyDefinition asm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(@"F:\files.fm\Code\asm_wrangler\asm_wrangler\bin\Debug\a.exe");

    MethodInfo writeLineMethod = typeof(Debug).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    MethodReference writeLine = asm.MainModule.Import(writeLineMethod);

    foreach (ModuleDefinition module in asm.Modules)
    {
        foreach (TypeDefinition type in module.Types)
        {
            foreach (var method in type.Methods)
            { 
                if (method.Name == "MyTask")
                {
                    var ins = method.Body.Instructions;
                    ins.Clear();
                    ILProcessor processor = method.Body.GetILProcessor();
                    
                    ins.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1));
                    
                    // ===> How to invoke Task.FromResult<bool>(true) here?
                    
                    ins.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need `MakeGenericMethod`, then you can call it like any other method**

```cs
var ins = method.Body.Instructions;

ILProcessor processor = method.Body.GetILProcessor();
                    
ins.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1));
ins.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Call,
    typeof(Task).GetMethod("FromResult").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool)))
ins.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
```